# How to transfer half-precision binary to decimal on hands?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

For example,

```
1 10000 0000000000 = −2
```

But why? Could anyone explain it a little bit with some example?

Answer (score 1):

Break it down:

```
+------------------- Sign
| +---+------------- Biased exponent
| |   | +--------+-- Fractional part of the significand 
1 10000 0000000000 = −2
```

Since the *biased exponent* field is neither a 0 nor the maximum value, this is a *normal number* with an implied `1.` for the significand and a biased exponent

```
significand = 1.Fractional_part_of_the_significand
```

With [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), the [Exponent bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) is 15.

```
exponent = Biased_exponent - Exponent_bias;
```

Put this together with `1 10000 0000000000` (`**` implies exponentiation)

```
value = (-1)**sign * 1.Fractional * 2**(Biased_exponent - Exponent_bias)
value = -1 * 1.0000000000(binary) * 2**(10000(binary) - 15)
value = -1 * 1.0 * 2**(16 - 15)
value = -2
```